# How to deploy Nodejs project on gcp without log in

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a client for whom I have created a project and deployed on his gcp. Now he changed the password and has forget the password, and there was changes that have done in his project and have to update it. So can anyone tell me how to update a project on VM without logging in, in the google cloud.

Comment: simply deploy a new instance with a new password... or tell him to get his password reset.

Comment: @MartinZeitler he is not in his country.. he is on world tour..

Comment: `GCP` is omnipresent ...accessing a VM without a login is outright absurd; unless SSH keys were retrieved - so that they could be presented to the SSHd. or when a service account had been setup, previously. if both isn't the case, there is no way.

Comment: (Let's not try migrating this question to _Server Fault_ folks - I am not sure they will be keen on a question of getting unauthorised access to a server!)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your administrator password in order to access your VM: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en

Comment: links are welcome but you should also report what it says with basic instructions